# Importing package in python terminal works, but it does not work in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pip, ipython, ipywidgets

I am getting error while importing `FileUpload` from `ipywidgets` in jupyter notebook:

[image]

However the same works when done in python interpreter:

[image]

As long as I can see from different command outputs, both jupyter notebook and python interpreter are running against same python installation and accessing same `ipywidgets`. Then, still why it is working in interpreter and not in jupyter notebook?

PS: both my python interter and jupyter notebook are running inside docker running on WSL in Windows 10.